# Django gives Field error when passed in a function. Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to order the albums with the 10 highest reviews, but when I order by the function "averageReview' it gives me a field error, what is the solution?

views:

```
def homeview(request):
    highest_rated = albums.objects.order_by('-averageReview')[9]
    album = albums.objects.all()
    return render(request, "home/home.html", {'albums' : album, 'highest_rated' : highest_rated })
```

models:

```
class albums(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(choices=GENRE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default2.jpg', upload_to='album_pics')

    @classmethod
    def averageReview(self):
        reviews = ReviewRating.objects.filter(album=self, status=True).aggregate(average=Avg('rating'))
        avg = 0
        if reviews['average'] is not None:
            avg = float(reviews['average'])
        return avg
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(albums, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject or f"ReviewRating #{self.pk}"
```

Comment: You can not order by a propery/classmethod. The classmethod will not even work by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The Django ORM converts the `QuerySet` to an SQL query. The database does not know anything about Python/Django, so it can not work with properties for example.

You can order by an annotation, so:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, F, Q


def homeview(request):
    highest_rated = (
        Album.objects.alias(
            avg_rating=Avg(
                'reviewrating__rating', filter=Q(reviewrating__status=True)
            )
        )
        .order_by(F('avg_rating').desc(nulls_last=True))
        .first()
    )
    album = Album.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'home/home.html',
        {'albums': album, 'highest_rated': highest_rated},
    )
```

As for the model, you can simplify (and correct) the property, with:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def averageReview(self):
        return (
            self.reviewrating_set.filter(status=True).aggregate(
                average=Avg('rating')
            )['average']
            or 0
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`albums`</s> to `Album`.

Comment: @NART: you need to import it `from django.db.models import Avg, F, Q`.